# Is what I have done to Show that each element of $(E_h)$ is written as a linear combination of the functions $(\phi)_ i$?

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-element-method, meshing

Let $\phi_{i}$ are continious over mesh every integer, and define $E_h=\text{vect}\{\phi_i, i=1,\cdots N\}$

I want to Show that each element of $(E_h)$ is written as a linear combination of the functions $(\phi)_ i$, and that these functions are linearly independent ?

**Attempt:** It is known that finit elements based on discret space of globally  continious function and affine over each mesh , I have defined this functional space :
$V_h=\{ v\in C([0,1]) \text{such that}:v|_{[x_j,x_{j+1}]} ,0\leq j\leq n \quad \text{and}\quad v(0)=v(1)=0\}$, Now we have for every $v\in V_h$ is defined with unique way as:$v_h(x)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}v_h(x_j)\phi_j(x),\forall x\in [0,1]$, Now we have immediately :$\phi_j(x_i)=\delta_{ij}$ which it is the Kronecker symbole it is $1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ else , but am not sure if I have showed each element of $(E_h)$ can be  written as a linear combination of the functions $(\phi)_ i$, and that these functions are linearly independent

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the possibility that $a_1\phi_1 + \ldots a_n\phi_n =0$, then add the fact that $\phi_i(x_j) =\delta_{ij} $, we find that all the $a_i$'s must be zero, and therefore the set is linearly independent.